# Compilation error when including eigen library

Tags: c++, makefile, build, eigen

I'm currently using eigen library, and this is the only file that I include eigen:
Kraftwerk2.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Kraftwerk2.h"

Kraftwerk2::Kraftwerk2(int n){ //n: num instances
    Connectivity_mat.resize(n,n);
}

int Kraftwerk2::Parse_Inst_Name(string s){ //input: String("M12"), output: int 12
    return stoi(s.substr(1));
}

void Kraftwerk2::Generate_Connectivity_matrix(unordered_map<string, net> map){
    for(auto& it : map){
        int n =it.second.net_pin.size();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
                Connectivity_mat(i,j) = Connectivity_mat(i,j) +1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Kraftwerk2::Print_Mat(){
    IOFormat CleanFmt(4, 0, ", ", "\n", "[", "]");
    cout << Connectivity_mat.format(CleanFmt);
}
```

Kraftwerk2.h:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include "module.h"
using namespace std;
//    unordered_map<string, instance> instances;
//    unordered_map<string, net> nets;
using namespace Eigen;

class Kraftwerk2{
    public:
        Kraftwerk2(int);
        MatrixXd Connectivity_mat;
        int Parse_Inst_Name(string);
        void Generate_Connectivity_matrix(unordered_map<string, net>);
        void Print_Mat();
};
```

And I use makefile for compiling:

(I'm pretty new to makefile, so if there's something I can improve, please tell me)
(Eigen is installed in the working directory ./eigen)

```
# CC and CFLAGS are varilables
CC = g++ 
CFLAGS = -c
OPTFLAGS = -O2

DBGFLAGS = -g -D_DEBUG_ON_
# make all
all : bin/partition
    @echo -n "make complete!"

# optimized version
bin/partition: main_opt.o FM.o partition.o module.o Kraftwerk2.o
    $(CC) $(OPTFLAGS) main_opt.o FM.o partition.o module.o Kraftwerk2.o -o bin/partition
main_opt.o: src/main.cpp  src/FM_alg.h src/partition.h src/module.h src/Kraftwerk2.h
    $(CC) -I ./eigen $< -o $@

FM.o: src/FM_alg.cpp src/FM_alg.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $< -o $@
partition.o: src/partition.cpp src/partition.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $< -o $@
Kraftwerk2.o: src/Kraftwerk2.cpp src/Kraftwerk2.h
    $(CC) ./eigen $(CFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $< -o $@
module.o: src/module.cpp src/module.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $< -o $@

# clean all the .o and executable files
clean:
        rm -rf *.o lib/*.a lib/*.o bin/*
```

However, when I make, the terminal seems to output some error that comes form the library itself(???

```
g++  -I ./eigen src/main.cpp -o main_opt.o
In file included from ./eigen/Eigen/Core:269,
                 from src/Kraftwerk2.h:2,
                 from src/main.cpp:4:
./eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/IndexedViewHelper.h:69:23: error: declaration of ‘template<class first> constexpr Eigen::Index Eigen::internal::first(const first&)’ shadows template parameter
   69 | EIGEN_CONSTEXPR Index first(const T& x) EIGEN_NOEXCEPT { return x.first(); }
      |                       ^~~~~
./eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/IndexedViewHelper.h:68:10: note: template parameter ‘first’ declared here
   68 | template<typename T>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [makefile:15: main_opt.o] Error 1
```

I would be so appreciated if anybody can tell me what's wrong with this.

Comment: In the makefile rule to make Kraftwerk2.o, why do you have `./eigen` without a -I flag in front of it?

Comment: What g++ version and what Eigen version are you using?